# Enable bytecode enhancement in kotlin using gradle

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, kotlin, jpa

I'm working on a project using Spring Boot 3 and JPA Repositories, implemented in Kotlin. I'm encountering an issue with enabling lazy loading for @OneToOne and @ManyToOne child entities from the owning side.

Problem:

Using the default fetch type LAZY does not seem to work as expected. When I fetch a single entity, it results in several round trips to the database, leading to the n+1 problem.

I've experimented with various approaches, such as including the optional attribute and trying LazyOneToOne, but none of these solutions have resolved the issue.

The last option I'm considering is enabling bytecode enhancement using the Hibernate Gradle Plugin. However, I'm facing issues with its setup. Here's the plugin configuration I'm using:

`plugins {     id("org.hibernate.orm") version "6.4.1.Final" }`

I'm following the guidelines from [Hibernate's GitHub repository](https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-orm/tree/main/tooling/hibernate-gradle-plugin), but I'm encountering several errors.

- An exception occurred applying plugin request [id: 'org.hibernate.orm', version: '6.4.1.Final']
- Caused by: org.gradle.api.reflect.ObjectInstantiationException: Could not create an instance of type org.hibernate.orm.tooling.gradle.HibernateOrmSpec.
- Caused by: org.gradle.api.UnknownDomainObjectException: SourceSet with name 'main' not found.

Questions:

Has anyone successfully implemented lazy loading for @OneToOne and @ManyToOne relationships in a similar setup? If so, how did you achieve it?
Specifically, has anyone used the Hibernate Gradle Plugin for bytecode enhancement in Spring Boot 3 with Kotlin? Did it resolve the lazy loading issues, and how did you configure it to work properly?
Any insights, suggestions, or experiences would be greatly appreciated!